# How to save state of CheckBox after exit?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

In my app ,one interface has some checkBoxes,I wish after I exit the interface, the CheckBoxes should maintain the state.So next time I enter it can show what I have done last time.I have used `SharedPreferrences` to achieve this.

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0).edit();
editor.putBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", isChecked);
editor.commit();
}
    });
checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("cbx2_ischecked", isChecked);
    editor.commit();
    }

});
```

But it doesn't work. when I return to this page, All checkBox show state that "every item is unselected ".

How can I realize the function I wish?

Comment: you will have to access cbx1_ischecked  and set them manually. you cannot expect it to automatically retrieve value of cbx1_ischecked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After put date getSharedPreferences, You have to initialize your checkboz state with this data in onCreate, like below

// onCreate

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0);
Boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", false);
checkbox1.setChecked(isChecked );
```

Comment: This looks good but you should use settings.getBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", false); because I think 0 will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are saved to `SharedPreferences`, but that doesn't mean they are automatically restored to the corresponding checkboxes. You need to read them from `SharedPreferences` and set your checkboxes when your activity starts, as @talhakosen mentioned.

Besides, you don't need to write your values to SharedPreferences every time they change. It would be enough to store them when user leaves your activity, i.e. in `onStop()` method.