# Can not save the state of CheckBox in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I am developing an application. There are many checkbox in one page. I want to save the state of CheckBox when I exit page. I use SharedPreferrences to save. The code is like this:

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0).edit();
editor.putBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", isChecked);
editor.commit();
}
    });
checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("cbx2_ischecked", isChecked);
    editor.commit();
    }

});
```

When I leave this page, and back again. All the checkbox state becomes not selected as default. why?

Comment: where you are setting checkbox?

Comment: And how are you set checkbox values from `SharedPreferences`.? Simple in your case. `onPause()` (store values in SharedPreferences) and `onResume()` (get values from SharedPreferences) works.

Comment: get all values when you reopen your app using
myPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
And set all check box values..

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/13560833/1626878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving vallues but you have to restore them you your activity is started like this :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0);
checkbox1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("cbx1_ischecked" ,false));
checkbox2.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("cbx2_ischecked" ,false));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 boolean check1,check2;
 checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  check1=isChecked;

 }
});

checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 check2=isChecked;

}

}); 

//store boolean only once when you leave the activity
 Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0).edit();
 editor.putBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", check1);
 editor.putBoolean("cbx2_ischecked", check2);
 editor.commit();


 In onCreate()

  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0);
  checkbox1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("cbx1_ischecked" ,false));
  checkbox2.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("cbx2_ischecked" ,false));
```